# A port is not open on firewall but it's accessible

Tags: docker, centos7, firewalld

I'm using centos 7 with firewallD on my server.

I have also installed docker on this machine and added it to a trusted zone of my firewall.

I have a container that listens on port `9081` but this port is not open on the firewall and the strange thing is that port is accessible from my home pc.

This is the output of `firewall-cmd --list-all`

```
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 443/tcp 80/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

I have two active zones : `trusted` and `public`

here is the output of command `firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --list-all`

```
trusted (active)
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: docker0
  sources:
  services:
  ports: 4243/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

Clearly the port `9081` is not open in any zone, but still, I can access it. why? how to close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that there are some errors running Docker with firewallD.

A Simple walkaround is to change how you define your ports in docker. in my case I had to change my docker-compose to this:

```
ports:
- "127.0.0.1:9081:8081"
```

The important part is using `127.0.0.1` in before defining host port.